# How do I find the smallest number in an array that's immediately larger than a given number in another array?

Tags: r

```
larger1temp = wbd663$mbsf[which(wbd663$mbsf > carb663$mbsf[i])]

larger1 = larger1temp[1]
```

^this is how I do it now, but there must be a far better way. it's a while loop, explaining the i.

Basically, `wbd663$mbsf` is an array of depths, as is `carb663$mbsf` also is an array of depths. i want to find the smallest depth value in `wbd663$mbsf` that's larger than a given `carb663$mbsf[i]` value.

Comment: What I meant by that is what do you do if you have several cases with the same result. Pick a random one, or are there other criteria that should be met?

Comment: Ah - hmm - maybe in that case you can maybe compare their dimensions in another column? Though the other answers did answer my original question perfectly well so you don't have to provide an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say I have vector A and I have item 4 of vector B.  The syntax to get the minimum item greater than item 4 of vector B is...

```
min(A[A > B[4])
```

But I'm a little concerned your question should really be elaborated given that you've got the index of B in a loop.  Do you really want each and every one of these minimums?

In that case you might use

```
sapply( B, function(x) min(A[A>x]) )
```

If this turns out to be a little slow you could probably speed it up by presorting and using direct indexing.  A simple version of that would be.

```
As <- sort(A)
sapply( B, function(x) As[As>x][1] )
```

(OK, actually, that's not any faster... not an amount faster I can see anyway)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @John. As an alternative to `sapply`, you can use `findInterval`, which is really fast

```
As <- sort(A)
id <- findInterval(B, A)
As[id+1] # NA if lub does not exist.
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to remember that command.  Questioner should select this as the best answer if they really want all of the values. But I'm leaving mine as a generalization and direct answer to what was asked.